# Can I change values in VBA a loop based on values in an accdb table

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, ms-access

I am using string values to convert unstructured wire details into official deal names for purpose of wire identification and management.  With over 200 deal names managing the code has become burdensome and I'd like to manage the wire identifying text and the official deal names in a database.

I have working code that converts the wire detail into the customer name and inserts into new column but it is all hard-coded into the VBA script and I'd like to make this process more systematic with database.  I'd like the code to iterate through changing the value of the 'Deal_Name' and 'Bank_String' for each column in the table.

```
Sub Test_Bank_Customer_Name()

Dim R As Range
Dim rngData As Range


Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)

For Each R In rngData.Rows

Select Case True

        Case UCase(Intersect(R, ActiveSheet.Range("AL:AL")).Text) Like UCase("*Bank_Identifier*") 
                    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & R.Row) = "Deal_Name" 'test each value of 'Bank_Identifier' and 'Deal_Name' in the accdb for each row in the report

End Select
Next R
End Sub
```

Each row in the destination file would have a value from the customer list based on the bank_string existing in column AL

Comment: Unless you're already familiar with using ADO to query an access database you'd find it easier to crearte a lookup table in excel and use that.

Comment: If you want a relational database, why is Excel involved?